# Tether from from testnet to mainnet

Tags: blockchain

I have quite a bit of tether and usdc I'm texting it. I am trying to transfer to mainnet how do I do that

Comment: Hi there. Any tokens that exist on a testnet are just that: test tokens for testing purposes, which have no intrinsic value. You can't transfer them to mainnet (unfortunately!) - that would be like printing money from thin air :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to transfer a token or a native coin from Testnet to Mainnet because they are two different environment and don't interconnected.